# NTFS log file specified size too small?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, chkdsk

I was checking my disks and it (`chkdsk X: /v /l /x /b`) says the log file size (65536 kB - default size) is too small, in each of my partitions, so I doubled it, and redoubled it, and it's now it's 1MB in my 2TB drive and it still says it's too small. What gives? What's an appropriate size for the log file, considering a nearly full 2TB disk with 800k files in 20k folders?

Answer (score 2):

The default size seems to depend on the partition size. I tested it with two partitions:

- C: 95 GB, default log file size 65536 KB
- F: 5 GB, default log file size 27648 KB

Changing the log file size for C: was not possible at all.
For F:, I found that the minimum size is 2048 KB (2 MB).

You wrote that you tried to set the log file to 1MB. If you really mean **M**B, it is to small. In fact you decreased the size, as 65536 KB are **64 MB**.

From [Table 28-3 Chkdsk Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457122.aspx):

> /l:size
>
> NTFS only. Changes the size of the log file to the specified **number of kilobytes**. Displays the current size if you do not enter a new size.

Thus, if you want to double the size, try the following command:

```
chkdsk x: /l:131072
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your set Event Log size.

> **considering a nearly full 2TB disk** with 800k files in 20k folders?

From Microsoft: [CHKDSK was unable to adjust the size of the log file.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms828668.aspx)

**Explanation:**

There is not enough space to increase the size of the log file, or Chkdsk encountered file system corruption on a clean volume.

**User Action:**

Delete some unneeded files and then run Chkdsk /f again.

Comment: The size was increased; when I say nearly full it's in the context of 2TB, the actual free space is ~5/6GB.

Comment: Another thing to check is to test your disk using the manufacturer's utilities, to ensure that you're not running into the "or Chkdsk encountered file system corruption on a clean volume" part.

Comment: If you noticed, this came in the process of checking the disks, as stated above. with 'chkdsk X: /v /l /x /b'.

Comment: Yes, but if you noticed, I suggested using the drive manufacturer's utilities to check the drive's health, not CHKDSK. ;)

Comment: No errors reported (by Seatools latest build, since it's 2 Samsung, plus one Seagate (data) drives), also it would be extremely unusual if all drive had the same problem simultaneously, since it's saying the same for all drives (a 500MB, a 1TB and a 2TB), and the mb is ok, as well. Couldn't find any info on this anywhere, either.